# Random String Appears After Token Symbol on Opensea

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin, opensea

I can't figure out why I'm getting this odd string after the Token symbol on Opensea with this NFT that I minted. The smart contract is below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract RizerNonRandom is ERC721URIStorage {
    uint256 public tokenCounter;
    constructor () public ERC721 ("RizerSeq", "RZRI"){
        tokenCounter = 0;
    }

    function createRizerNonRandom(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newItemId = tokenCounter;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

And here is what it looks like on Opensea.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is taken from the token's metadata. You need to call tokenURI on your token, and see what the metadata that is being returned. OpenSea grabs the collection name and token name from there.

So the issue is with the "tokenURI" you supplied to `createRizerNonRandom`.

Comment: Oh thanks I will try this. How do I call tokenURI?

Comment: You can go to Etherscan, go to your contract address, and if you verified the source code, in the Contract tab you can use "read contract" and "write contract" to call functions.

Comment: Turns out I didn't verify the source code. Is there any other way to call tokenURI? Or verify the source code after the fact?

Comment: I think you can use this tool: https://evmconnector.dev/ . Regarding verifying after the fact, it's possible but might not work. Try through etherscan website or hardhat-verify plugin.

Comment: First of all amazing resource! evmconnector.dev was perfect, thank you so much for the link! I got the tokenURI but it looks fine... lol. It's just the perfectly formatted metadata... See: https://imgur.com/a/Oo7SIas

Comment: Hmm you're right, it does look OK. Did you yourself add the the smart contract to OpenSea? If yes, you can edit it (pencil icon) and probably change this name. If not, you should add it from the Collections menu I think, you press the dots and do from smart contract. Try this.